# I want to make certain text in my rails log a different color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make sure all the lines that look like this (basically, lines that contain rails benchmarking info)

```
  Rendered search/_sidebar.html.erb (1.0ms)
```

... are outlined in a different color.
How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try this](http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/beautiful-logging-for-your-ruby-on-rails-application) It's how I color code my logs. There is a separate link in the page if you're using rails 3.2